# Automatic file system synchronization between different machines

Tags: windows, linux, file-synchronization

I use multiple machines (a desktop PC and a laptop), and I'm looking for a way to keep the files I'm working on synchronized between all machines. The solution must meet these requirements:

- Works on both Windows and Linux
- Can be configured to transparently synchronize an existing folder structure
- Allows access to the files even when no internet connection is available
- Allows access to the files during the synchronization process
- Synchronizes files without manual invocation
- Must store files on a user-controlled server (ideally via SSH) and not someone else's "Cloud"

What would also be nice to have, but is not strictly necessary for me:

- File metadata synchronization (permissions + modification time in particular)
- Free/Libre Software

Ideally, I'd boot up one machine, work on stuff, and when I boot up another box, all my changes are there as if I had made them on the box I just started.

The solution I use right now is rather limited. I wrote a simple shell script that invokes rsync to copy all files to or from a central server via SSH. This has a few drawbacks:

- If I forget to push my changes to the server, they are unavailable on all other machines.
- If I forget to pull changes from the server, the next pull will overwrite all changes I made locally.
- It doesn't work on Windows without installing a huge package like Cygwin.

I also explored ownCloud, but it has some disadvantages as well.

- Requires a full webserver stack with PHP and a SQL database
- On Windows, it would lock files during the synchronization. Particularly annoying while writing or compiling code in short intervals
- On Linux, it used some virtual filesystem capabilities that could only be easily accessed from a graphical file explorer

Comment: [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) might fit your needs. As I've not yet used it myself, I cannot tell for sure – but should definitely be worth a look.

Comment: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/ . Just to cross-synchronization without clouds, torrents and other third parties

Answer (score 3):

What you need is [BitTorrent Sync](https://www.getsync.com/platforms/desktop).

It meets all your requirements:

- Works on both Windows and Linux
- Can be configured to transparently synchronize an existing folder structure
- Allows access to the files even when no internet connection is available
- Allows access to the files during the synchronization process
- Synchronizes files without manual invocation

It also satisfies your requirement of "Must store files on a user-controlled server (ideally via SSH) and not someone else's Cloud", yet does so with more flexibility than you probably imagine.  You don't even need a server; the systems simply sync with each other.

Here is a screenshot of the user interface:
[image]

Disclosure: I contributed to the pre-release and post-release testing of this product.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The website talks about "Device to device file transfer" - how does that work if one of the machines is turned off? If there is no server, how does machine B pull the changes from machine A when machine A is turned off?

Comment: Good questions.  When machine A is turned back on, they will sync.  The alternative is to set up machine C, which replaces the traditional server.  In this case, machines A, B, and C are automatically kept in sync, with machine C always on, thus acting like a server.  The advantage is that machine C is actually a fully usable system and does not have to kept isolated like a traditional server.  The BitTorrent Sync software is quite light and surprisingly easy on resources.

Comment: No matter what solution you use, at least one system needs to be powered on for the sync to start. I use BitTorrent Sync as well, for this purpose, with 4 systems: a linux server in my home, my work laptop, my tablet, and my home laptop.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good independent solution: [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net).
Works on both Desktop and Android. Synchronizes files completely confidentially and does not send them to third-party servers. Can synchronize folders on different devices completely automatically.